# How do I do a greater than operation on a dataset when the date is kept in a string field as opposed to floating timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, rest

I am trying to return all values in a set that have been timestamped after a certain date.

The issue is that the date is a string and not a date/time format field. The dates are in the formate YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2020-01-01)

https://data.seattle.gov/resource/ez4a-iug7.json?$query=SELECT location1 WHERE TO_DATE(opendate,'YYYY-MM-DD') > '2020-01-01'

I have tried the above code to convert but it does nothing. The location1 and opendate are both the names of columns relevant to my search.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: *The issue is that the date is a string and not a date/time format field. The dates are in the formate YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2020-01-01)* The value in such format may be used as date-typed value directly. PS. There is no TO_DATE() function in MySQL. Do you really use MySQL? check carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
select location1 WHERE str_TO_DATE(opendate,'%Y %m %d') > '2020-01-01'
```

Example:
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
**Query #1**

    select str_to_date('2021 05 01','%Y %m %d') Date;

| Date       |
|------------|
| 2021-05-01 |



[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)
```

Comment: {
    "code": "query.compiler.malformed",
    "error": true,
    "message": "Could not parse SoQL query \"SELECT location1 WHERE str_TO_DATE(opendate,'�20�20�27) > '2020-01-01'\" at line 1 character 60",
    "data": {
        "query": "SELECT location1 WHERE str_TO_DATE(opendate,'�20�20�27) > '2020-01-01'",
        "position": {}
    }
}

Comment: Which dbms you are using? which version? And please share a sample string value you are trying to convert into date.

Comment: I am querying a REST API. A sample string I want to turn into a date then filter based off of would be '2020-01-25'

Comment: @ChrisBurnett is str_TO_DATE(opendate,'�20�20�27) quivalent of str_TO_DATE(opendate,'%Y %m %d') ? then you are missing (') ater 27 . if not then please use str_TO_DATE(opendate,'%Y %m %d') instead.